# Celery in Django (RabbitMQ vs. Django Database)

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, celeryd

I am trying to set up Django with Celery so I can send bulk emails in the background.

I am a little confused about how the different components play into Celery. Do I need to use RabbitMQ? Can I just "django-kombu" to run Celery? (http://ask.github.com/celery/tutorials/otherqueues.html#django-database)

I started with "First Steps with Django" in the django-celery docs (http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html), but when I get to "Running the celery worker server" this happens:

```
$ python manage.py celeryd -l info
[2011-09-02 18:35:00,150: WARNING/MainProcess]  

 -------------- celery@Sauls-MacBook.local v2.3.1
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** ---   . broker:      amqplib://guest@localhost:5672/
- ** ----------   . loader:      djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
- ** ----------   . logfile:     [stderr]@INFO
- ** ----------   . concurrency: 2
- ** ----------   . events:      OFF
- *** --- * ---   . beat:        OFF
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [Queues]
 --------------   . celery:      exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery


[Tasks]
  . tasks.add

[2011-09-02 18:35:00,213: INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[2011-09-02 18:35:00,214: INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[2011-09-02 18:35:00,229: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Sauls-MacBook.local has started.
[2011-09-02 18:35:00,276: ERROR/MainProcess] Consumer: Connection Error: [Errno 61} Connection refused. Trying again in 2 seconds...
[2011-09-02 18:35:02,283: ERROR/MainProcess] Consumer: Connection Error: [Errno 61] Connection refused. Trying again in 4 seconds...
```

Then I have to quit the process...

Answer (score 4):

As I can see from your configuration, you didn't set correctly the transport, in fact celery is trying to use amqplib for a connection to a broker like Rabbit MQ

```
broker:      amqplib://guest@localhost:5672/
```

You should set, in the settings.py, the broker backend in this way:

```
BROKER_BACKEND = "djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try this out and let you know how it goes.